# async and Q promises in nodejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, q, node-async

I'm using the [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) library and [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library in nodejs.

Here's an example of my code:

```
async.each(items, cb, function(item) {

 saveItem.then(function(doc) {
    cb();
 });

}, function() {

});
```

`saveItem` is a promise.  When I run this, I always get `cb is undefined`, I guess `then()` doesn't have access.  Any ideas how to work around this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your issue doesn't lie with promises, it lies with your usage of `async`.

`async.each(items, handler, finalCallback)` applies `handler` to every item of the `items` array. The `handler` function is asynchronous, i.e. it is handed a callback, that it must call when it has finished its work. When all handlers are done, the final callback is called.

Here's how you'd fix your current issue:

```
var handler = function (item, cb) {
  saveItem(item)
  .then(
    function () { // all is well!
        cb();
    },
    function (err) { // something bad happened!
        cb(err);
    }
  );
}

var finalCallback = function (err, results) {
  // ...
}

async.each(items, handler, finalCallback);
```

---

However, you don't need to use `async` for this particular piece of code: promises alone fill this job quite nicely, especially with [`Q.all()`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination):

```
// Create an array of promises
var promises = items.map(saveItem);

// Wait for all promises to be resolved
Q.all(promises)
.then(
    function () { // all is well!
        cb();
    },
    function (err) { // something bad happened!
        cb(err);
    }
)
```

Comment: Great you mentioned `Q.all` solution

Comment: Hot code. Will definitely be using this for fun and profit. :)